Can I use 'nvm use' in Jenkins pipeline?
I have an Windows Jenkins agent running a pipeline which should build an Angular application. Beforehand, I want to change my node version which should be used, as there are other Angular projects which are built on this agent as well (there might be different node versions used across projects).
As the pipeline is executing the nvm use ..., the pipeline is basically doing nothing - no errors, no output. I tried several things I found on the internet, like executing from powershell, (temporarily) disabling UAC, using a .nvmrc, ensuring the PATH is set correctly, redirecting the standard/error output to a file and so on.
I tried to execute nvm list to test as well, but the behaviour was exactly the same as when executing nvm use ....
Now my question is: Why do nvm commands do nothing when running in an Jenkins environment?

What is nvm in your case? https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows ? It has nothing to do with regular nvm except name and purpose. Did you try fnm?

@EstusFlask exactly, i use nvm for Windows. I have never used regular nvm to be honest, so would you mind giving me some input where fnm is operating differently compared to nvm for Windows? thanks a lot!

I'd use fnm instead of nvm-win by default now, I have better experience with it. Whether it works on your side could give more info on the root cause
